# Passing AngularJS variable to PHP/mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, variables

I'm attempting to pass an AngularJS variable to a mysql query. I can't figure out why it won't work. Here is the code:

```
$test = "{{tvShows[whatShow].tvdb_id}}";

$query = "SELECT * FROM tv_seasons WHERE EXISTS (SELECT tvdb_id FROM tv_episodes WHERE tv_episodes.tvdb_id=tv_seasons.tvdb_id AND tv_episodes.season=tv_seasons.season) AND tvdb_id = '";
$query .= $test;
$query .= "' ORDER BY CAST('episode' AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)";

$results = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){      
    print_r($row);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

`$test` echos properly and the query looks correct and when pasted into phpMyAdmin works as expected but when I try to do this it wont work for some reason. Any thoughts?

Comment: AngularJS variable in PHP? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: i'm learning AngularJS and i'm currently using a mysql database. In order to use said db I need to use php and in order to perform the query i need to i need to get the value of an AngularJS variable and pass it to my query in php. confusing.. i know.

Comment: Have you head of POST requests? or GET?

Comment: It wouldn't help me as it's not in the url..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post it to server like that([angular requests docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)):

```
$http.post(your_script_uri, {your_var_key: your_var}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
});;
```

Then on server side:

```
$_POST['your_var_key'] // use POST superglobal to access data you have posted
```

[$_POST docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Your code, modified:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tv_seasons WHERE EXISTS (SELECT tvdb_id FROM tv_episodes WHERE tv_episodes.tvdb_id=tv_seasons.tvdb_id AND tv_episodes.season=tv_seasons.season) AND tvdb_id = '";
$query .= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tvdb_id']);
$query .= "' ORDER BY CAST('episode' AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)";

$results = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){      
  print_r($row);
  echo "<br>";
}
```

PS: stop using `mysql` extension. It is deprecated in favor of mysqli extension.